# Is there a way to use vue router in background.js vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

Is there a way to access Vue router and components methods from background.js file?
I'm trying to normally import router from `./router/index.js` but the whole app breaks.